# Void pointer to a class object: Initialization inside a function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, void-pointers

I am trying to create a void pointer to a class object and have it be initialized inside a function. Unfortunately, the array member of the class cannot escape the function i.e. it cannot be accessed after initialization.

In the code below, the first call to print positions (inside the initialize function) works properly, however, the second call to print positions from outside the initialization function fails. I have a feeling that the array object created in the initialization function is destroyed and not passed along but I am not sure and also don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


class Atoms
{
    double * positions;
    int nAtoms;

    public:
        // Standard constructor prividing a pre-existant array
        Atoms(int nAtoms, double * positionsArray)
        {
            this->nAtoms = nAtoms;
            this->positions = positionsArray;
        }

        // Print positions to screen
        void print_positions()
        {
            std::cout<< "nAtoms: " << this->nAtoms << std::endl;
            int nDim = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < nAtoms; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nDim; j++)
                {
                    std::cout << std::setw(6) << this->positions[i * nDim + j] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

};


void initialize_Atoms_void_pointer(void ** voidAtomsPointer)
{
    //Create a new instance of Atoms by a pointer
    int numAtoms = 5;
    int numDim = 3;
    int elemN = numAtoms * numDim;
    double data_array[elemN];

    for (int i = 0; i < numAtoms; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < numDim; j++)
    {
        data_array[i * numDim + j] = i * numDim + j + 10;
    }
    Atoms *atoms = new Atoms(numAtoms, data_array);

    // Set the vPointer that the void pointer points to a pointer to Atoms object
    *voidAtomsPointer = static_cast<void *>(atoms);

    //Test call
    std::cout << std::endl << "Initializing atoms" << std::endl;
    static_cast<Atoms *>(*voidAtomsPointer)->print_positions();
}


void print_Atoms_pointer_positions(void * voidAtomsPointer)
{
    //Cast the pointer as an atoms pointer
    Atoms *atomsPointer = static_cast<Atoms *>(voidAtomsPointer);

    atomsPointer->print_positions();
}

int main()
{
    //Use the initializer function for getting a pointer
    void *testVoidAtomsPointer;

    initialize_Atoms_void_pointer(&testVoidAtomsPointer);
    print_Atoms_pointer_positions(testVoidAtomsPointer);
}
```

Comment: Besides the array being local which is your core problem, another problem is that `elemN` is not a compile time constant expression, so it is ill-formed to use it as the size of the array. This is easy to fix by adding `const`.

Comment: `new`, `void*`. Even C++98 had `std::vector`, and C++11 introduced `std::shared_ptr<>`. This code is really suffering because it's reinventing the wheel, poorly.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, in this problem, I am somewhat constrained only to use the very basic tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
Atoms *atoms = new Atoms(numAtoms, data_array);
```

`data_array` is a local array, which is destroyed when `initialize_Atoms_void_pointer` quits.

Instead of copying the raw pointer, make a new allocation in `Atoms`'s constructor and copy the content:

```
Atoms(int nAtoms, double * positionsArray)
{
  this->nAtoms = nAtoms;
  this->positions = new double[nAtoms];
  for (int ii = 0; ii < nAtoms; ++ii)
    this->positions[ii] = positionsArray[ii];
}

~Atoms()
{
  delete[] this->positions;
}
```

A safer implementation would include the use of a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which will automatically de-allocate the memory for you when `Atoms` is destroyed:

```
#include <memory>

class Atoms {
  std::unique_ptr<double[]> positions;
  // ...

public:
  Atoms(int nAtoms, double * positionsArray) :
    positions(new double[nAtoms]) {
    this->nAtoms = nAtoms;
    for (int ii = 0; ii < nAtoms; ++ii)
      this->positions[ii] = positionsArray[ii];        
  }

  // ...
};
```

You'd need also to check if `nAtoms` is 0 or negative, if the input array is null, etc., but I think it falls out of the scope of the question.

If you need to access the raw pointer, you can use the `positions.get()` method (do not try to delete it or your application will crash due to a double delete).

**Update**

Of course, another more straightforward solution is simply to use a `std::vector<double>` instead ;)

```
#include <vector>

class Atoms {
  std::vector<double> positions;
  // int nAtoms; -- no longer necessary

public:
  Atoms(int nAtoms, double * positionsArray) :
    positions(nAtoms) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < nAtoms; ++ii)
      this->positions[ii] = positionsArray[ii];      
  }

  // ...
};
```

If you need to access the raw pointer, you can use the `positions.data()` method (do not try to delete it or your application will crash due to a double delete). The number of atoms can be checked using `positions.size()`.

As mentioned in a comment, if the only purpose of the `Atoms` class is to store doubles but not to add any other operation, then just forget about it and directly use the `std::vector<double>`.